# Contains Inside relationship between regions algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I have two regions defined by the points they contain.

That is a region is a list of points {X, Y}.

Each region is connected.

One region is inside the other.

I need an algorithm to identify what region is inside.

Can some one provide me a link to an algorithm to solve this problem ?

If someone know an opencv function that solve this problem is very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a convex hull problem?

Comment: @Glenn I don't think so, the region don't need to be convex at all, I only need to know which one is inside the other. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: This is just a set intersection problem. Each region can be considered a set, obtain the intersection between them and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as none of the points of the outer shape is inside the points of the inner shape this can be done by a point location algorithm in linear time. Choose a point from the larger of the two sets and check if it is inside the other region by ray casting. See [Point in Polygon problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). A comprehensive set of implementations in multiple languages is here: [ray casting implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm).